# definite integral of form G(cos(x), sin(x)) by complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Given: the following integral:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{sin}(3x)}{5-3\mathrm{cos}(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x = 0
$$
Prove it by using complex integration and the residue theorem. But I do something wrong somewhere. This is my process:

So I start off by defining $z = \mathrm{e}^{xi}$, from which follows that $\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{iz}$, $\mathrm{sin}(3x) = \frac{z^3 - z^{-3}}{2i}$, $\mathrm{cos}(x) = \frac{z + z^{-1}}{2}$ and the contour $C$ is $|z| = 1$, the unity circle around 0. This leads to the following contour integral: 
$$
\oint_C \frac{z^3 - z^{-3}}{2i} * \frac{1}{5 - 3\frac{z + z^{-1}}{2}} * \frac{1}{iz}\mathrm{d}z = \oint_C \frac{z^4 - z^{-2}}{z(-3z^2+10z-3)}\mathrm{d}z
$$
So, now the poles: 
$$
z = 0, z = \frac{1}{3}, z = 3
$$
$z = 3$ lies outside the contour of intergration, so we are going to do the residue theorem for $z = 0$ and $z = \frac{1}{3}$, because:
$$
\oint_C f(z)\mathrm{d}z = 2\pi i(res(a) + res(b))
$$
So, $a = 0$
$$
res(a) = \lim\limits_{z\to0}\frac{z(z^4 - z^{-2})}{z(-3z^2+10z-3)} = \lim\limits_{z\to0} \frac{5z^4 + z^{-2}}{-9z^2 + 20z - 3} = 0
$$
By l'Hoptials rule. So, now the actual problem: the other one doesn't seem to be zero.
$$
res(b) = \lim\limits_{z\to\frac{1}{3}} \frac{(z-\frac{1}{3})(z^4 - z^{-2})}{z(-3z^2+10z-3)} = \lim\limits_{z\to\frac{1}{3}}\frac{(z^4 - z^{-2}) + (z-\frac{1}{3})(4z^3 + 2z^{-3})}{{-9z^2 + 20z - 3}} = -\frac{91}{27}
$$
By l'Hopitals rule. So in total, my solution is
$$
-2\pi i\frac{91}{27}
$$
Which is wrong, but why? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your $dz$ should be $dz/(iz)$ as you've mentioned.

Comment: That was a small mistake, but the right side does include that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$z = 0$ is a third order pole. Calculate it as such and the answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

To use complex analysis looks like an overkill, since:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin(3x)}{5-3\cos x}\,dx =-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(3x)}{5+3\cos x}\,dx$$
and the integral of an odd integrable function over an interval symmetric with respect to the origin is trivially zero.

Comment: I do agree with you, but the assignment specifically tells us to use the residu method.

Comment: In the same spirit, one participant was asked to use Newton-Raphson for a problem which reduces to a quadratic equation. Why should we make things simple since we can make them complex ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_Made_Difficult - we should write a second edition :D

Comment: Do you really want we try ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: no, I was just joking, but maybe by harvesting some material here on MSE the dream will become true, one day.